# Get country in "en" from other language

Tags: android, location, autocompletetextview, google-translate

My `AutoCompleteTextView` works fine, but I need return the response at the language of user, for this I use:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

The problem is when I need send to the backend the response in english (en).

For example:

I receive the next location: "Barcelona, España"

And I need send to the backend: "Barcelona, Spain"

this is my `AutocompleteTextView`

```
private void initilizeAutoCompleteTextView() {

    CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation, CustomFontHelper.FONT_BOLD, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter placesAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation.setAdapter(placesAdapter);

    mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation.setHint(mUser.getCountry());

    mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onLocationItemClick(parent, view, position, id);

            ViewHelper.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
        }
    });

}

void onLocationItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String description = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation.setTag(description);

    doCallback(mAutoCompleteTextViewLocation.getTag().toString());

}
```

If anyone knows a solution I would be very grateful.